# Why do I get Ora-30004 when sys_connect_by_path delimiter is not present in column values

Tags: oracle

I have tested this on Oracle versions:
11.2.0.3.0
12.1.0.2.0

The following query throws an ORA-30004 error, but my delimiter of ' -> ' is not used in any of the column values:

```
with temptable as (
  select '2624' as id, 'ninechars' as label, '' as parentid from dual union 
  select '2625' as id, 'erewrettt' as label, '2624' as parentid from dual union 
  select '2626' as id, 'Im stumped' as label, '' as parentid from dual union 
  select '2627' as id, '- Unknown -' as label, '' as parentid from dual
)
select sys_connect_by_path(label, ' -> ' ) 
from temptable
start with parentid is null 
connect by prior id = parentid;
```

**Some observations:**

> - Changing the value "ninechars" to "ninecharsx" allows the query to work
> - Changing the value "ninechars" to "abcdefghi" also breaks the query
>
>   - It seems like all nine character values here break the query
> - Leaving the value as "ninechars" and removing the last union statement, which is not connected to any of the other records, allows
>     the query to work
> - Changing the delimiter from ' -> ' to ' *> ' allows the query to work

**Question**
What is the source of the ORA-30004 error?  Why does Oracle think that the delimiter is appearing as part of a column value?

Edit: Thanks to bobdylan for this [pastebin.com/Ad1edFcJ](http://pastebin.com/Ad1edFcJ)  link left in the comments that helps illustrate the issue

Comment: this works and yields results on 11.1.0.7.0

Comment: Works on 12.1.0.2.0 too.

Comment: Also works OK on 11.2.0.3.0 and 11.2.0.4.7 on Linux. Are you sure that's the server version not, say, the SQL\*Plus version? There are a few bugs for this error on MOS but nothing that looks like it should affect either of those versions. Which client are running this from? If it's reproducible it may be time to raise a service request.

Comment: I too am getting the same error as user1333371 on 11.2.0.4

Comment: Which O/S is your server running, and which client (and version) are you using?

Comment: I've *kinda* figured it out. the issue is from the final '- unknown -' value. It seems to be taking this as some function rather than as a string. I'm not sure of the technicals around this: see http://pastebin.com/Ad1edFcJ for a spool. As you can see you can 'break' it by changing the final value. It also resolves if you have a parent id (rather than '') but this isn't shown.

Comment: By the way the reference manual says about **char** separator. Does it seem to be it has to be **one character** value?  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions198.htm

Comment: @AlexPoole.  I used SELECT version FROM V$INSTANCE to get the Oracle version.  I tried running the query from within SQL*Plus and without and got the same error.  I'm on a linux O/S, but I'm not sure how that matters.  Other users have replicated the issue too

Comment: Works for me on 12.1.0.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like a bug. If you need to workaround it and implement your logic, alternatively you can use recursive subquery factoring (recursive With), which works alright in 11.2.0.4:

```
SQL> with t (id, label, parentid, reportlevel, fake_connect_by_path) as (
  2  select id, label, parentid, 0 as reportlevel, ' -> ' || label as fake_connect_by_path
  3    from temptable
  4   where parentid is null
  5   union all
  6  select tt.id, tt.label, tt.parentid, reportlevel + 1, t.fake_connect_by_path || ' -> ' || tt.label as fake_connect_by_path
  7    from temptable tt
  8    join t on t.id = tt.parentid
  9  )
 10  select fake_connect_by_path
 11    from t;
FAKE_CONNECT_BY_PATH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -> ninechars
 -> Im stumped
 -> - Unknown -
 -> ninechars -> erewrettt
```

Comment: This is an acceptable workaround.  In the end, I chose a different workaround that involved using a 1 character delimiter that doesn't appear in any of the column values and the replace function.  So replace(sys_connect_by_path(label, '|'), '|', ' -> ')