# Oracle ORA-30004 SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH if whitespace at the beginning of separator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

We have a lot of queries with `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`, which have worked fine until now. Now we get really strange behaviour.
It breaks down to this:

```
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(title, ' > ')
--
Java::JavaSql::SQLException: ORA-30004: when using 
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function, cannot have separator as part of column value
```

Now the strange thing is, it only happens on some elements, which are not in any kind different from the others.

And yes, there is no `' > '` in the data, there is not even a `>` in the whole data.

And now the strange part. As soon as the starting space is removed, the query works:

```
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(title, '> ') // works
```

This is true for every seperator string:

```
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(title, ' asdsahjkwer!!!+*+::+:+*+_A_A:X"I') //fails
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(title, 'asdsahjkwer!!!+*+::+:+*+_A_A:X"I')  //works
```

This smells like a bug for me, have you any experience with a similar behaviour? Is there a good workaround?

The exact db version is:

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

Comment: The only way I can replicate this in Oracle 11.2.0.1 is when there is a `title` containing the separator as a sub-string. Can you post a [MCVE] (DDL and DML statements) with some sample data that replicates the issue on your version?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit In Oracle 11.2, trying `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(title, ' '||'> ')` gives `ORA-30003: illegal parameter in SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function`. The second one works (but only if the separator is not a sub-string of the title - as I still can't replicate the OP's issue on a different version).

Comment: A suitable workaround could be `REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(title, '>'), '>', ' > ')` as you say `>` does not appear in the data.

Comment: @MT0 I am trying, but it is quite complex, and since the error happens only in specific cases, it is quite hard to nail it down. `title` does not contain the separator, if it would contain it, `'>'`would also fail.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes this is a workarround, but since it does not explain the error at all, i can't be sure it would solve the problem permamently (There are a lot of workarrounds possible like this). But thank you for your effort anyway.

Comment: It is as said, really hard to show it to you, but i am pretty sure it is a bug ( since changes at unrelated parts of the query, can solve the error), hence i do not think it is solvable here. This post has a quite similar problem with a Minmal example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018473/why-do-i-get-ora-30004-when-sys-connect-by-path-delimiter-is-not-present-in-colu